# How do I use the printf function while keeping columns organized?

Tags: java, printf, stringbuilder

I'm trying to print out an invoice report in java for a project but am having trouble formatting the sheet. This is the code that I'm having problems with.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
sb.append(String.format("%s%s%-82s%s%10.2f%s","DISCOUNT ( ","Placeholder"," )", "$", 99.99, "\n"));
```

Which prints out this

```
DISCOUNT ( Placeholder )                                                                                $     99.99
```

If I change the character length of the word "Placeholder," the $99.99 column is moved, as such.

```
DISCOUNT ( p )                                                                                $     99.99
```

What I need for the code to do is whether the word "Placeholder" is replaced with a word 10 characters long or 1 character long, the $99.99 needs to stay in the same place so it is in the correct column when I print. I tried modifying the %s for the $ but it seems to still move if Placeholder is changed. Advice?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the width parameter.
Something like this (15 is the width here):

```
System.out.printf("%s%15s%-82s%s%10.2f%s", "DISCOUNT ( ", "Placeholder", " )", "$", 99.99, "\n");
```

Not sure if String.format uses exactly the same syntax as printf though.

The output will be:

```
DISCOUNT (     Placeholder )                                           $     99,99
DISCOUNT (               p )                                           $     99,99
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just calculate the length of the format by subtracting the length of the placeholder from a specific value.

```
private static String placeHolder = "";
private static int value;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    setPlaceHolder("");
    sb.append(String.format("%s%s%-"+value+"s%s%10.2f%s","DISCOUNT ( ",placeHolder," )", "$", 99.99, "\n"));
    setPlaceHolder("Placeholder");
    sb.append(String.format("%s%s%-"+value+"s%s%10.2f%s","DISCOUNT ( ",placeHolder," )", "$", 99.99, "\n"));
    setPlaceHolder("This is quite some long text");
    sb.append(String.format("%s%s%-"+value+"s%s%10.2f%s","DISCOUNT ( ",placeHolder," )", "$", 99.99, "\n"));
    System.out.println(sb);
}

private static void setPlaceHolder(String placeholder) {
    placeHolder = placeholder;
    value = 83 - placeholder.length();
}
```

the output

```
DISCOUNT (  )                                                                                 $     99,99
DISCOUNT ( Placeholder )                                                                      $     99,99
DISCOUNT ( This is quite some long text )                                                     $     99,99
```